# Is the term "step-action table" jargon?

Tags: terminology, business-language, tech-writing

I'm an engineer.  My doc team has been using step-action tables to create user-facing documentation for some software that I've built recently.  I think these tables are awesome, but I keep seeing them prefixed with a sentence of the form:

> The following step-action table contains the procedure for kerfumbulating the fooziewhatsits:

My question is: Should the term "step-action table" just be "table"?

Comment: It may depend who the sentence is addressed to. If you're writing to other software engineers, call it what you link; but, if - as you imply - this is documentation for the user, and the user is the general public, then do not use technical terms.  I have never heard of a 'step-action table' despite working with computers since the days of DOS.

Comment: You have an action plan with steps. Step One, Step Two. That is not step-action table. It's better to use Step/Action Table. In my opinion. And it's not a computer term. It's a "change management" "thing". Actually: action step table is really the meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a software engineer.  I'm not clear on what you mean by "step-action table".  I can infer it's definition from context, usage, and the definition of the component words.  However, I think this places it clearly within the realm of jargon.

> My question is: Should the term "step-action table" just be "table"?

Yes.

Comment: No, they are the steps you take in your action plan. Your /action step table/ is the way to adjectivize it.

Answer (score 1):

The term "Step/Action Table" is part of the Information Mapping way of presenting information.  It provides a structure for stepping users of information through a process.  It also serves as a structure to present information that can't/shouldn't be listed in bullet or numbered form - for different reasons. So the Title of the table can be "Step/Action" if you are using the Information Mapping format.  Or just "Table".  Whichever you want.  http://www.informationmapping.com/en/

Comment: https://informationmapping.app.box.com/s/xaxgrrsb9qfm4vtnptmktpm9tw75p1oq

Comment: All I see in the link in your answer is what looks like a home page for a company.

Comment: Thanks Ann for the example in your comment link.  That's exactly the structure I'm describing.  I think it also reinforces Nathan's answer of "Yes" however, since the audience here is fooziewhatsit kerfumbulators and not documentation professionals.

Answer (score 0):

I think a lot of times, those who like to bloviate grab jargon, which I consider "step action" to be.  Someone above mentioned "Step/Action" and this sounds more legitimate.  I often wonder if folks mean to say action steps and revert to trying to sound fluent in "jargon."